# RecyclerView и вывод элементов, которые в нем не содержатся

Tags: android, android-layout, recyclerview

Есть два списка: первый с именами, второй с фамилиями

Нужно их вывести на одном `Activity` с помощью `RecyclerView`. Как именно это лучше реализовать если сам `layout` должен выглядеть подобным образом:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дизайн и размеры не имеют значения, важна именно сама реализация и нужная разметка.

Как лучше реализовать подобное? Использовать `RecyclerView` в количестве двух штук (каждый под свой список), или каким-то образом использовать один? К примеру, чтобы после конца первого списка, выводился `TextView`, а за ним сразу шел второй список? 
Набросал макет, раскритикуйте, пожалуйста

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/textView_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: вам нужно разобраться с назначением метода `getItemViewType()` в адаптере.

Comment: @pavlofff но ведь тогда будет потеря данных нет?
Мне нужно, чтобы 2 эти списка разделялись и отображались все данные. А как я понял, при использовании `getItemViewType` он *вместо*, к примеру, 20 позиции (где лежат какие-то данные уже) вставляет новую view, а данные по этой 20 позиции никак не используются. Из решений представляю себе только изначальный сдвиг массива на 1 элемент, чтобы в той позиции в которой нужно, было пусто, но это костыльно вроде бы

Comment: @whalemare Вы можете в методе `getItemViewType()` определять первый элемент каждого блока данных и выводить для него другой вид айтема, такой же как и прочие, но с надписью сверху. Надпись можно как захардкорить и выводить разные айтемы для первого и второго блока с соответствующей надписью, так и определять в `onBindViewHolder()`, какой блок данных сейчас выводится и биндить соответствующюю надпись (предпочтительный вариант).